# how to change CWD for a command executed in Julia?

Tags: shell, julia

Julia doesn't use shell like other languages for [running external programs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/running-external-programs/). How can I do the equivalent of `cd temp_dir && some_cmd` in Julia? As far as I understand `cd()` changes the working directory globally which is a problem if I execute blocks of code in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docstring for the `cd` function:

```
help?> cd
search: cd Cdouble gcd gcdx secd vecdot asecd cld Cmd codeunit CodeInfo

  cd(dir::AbstractString=homedir())

  Set the current working directory.

  cd(f::Function, dir::AbstractString=homedir())

  Temporarily changes the current working directory and applies function f
  before returning.
```

We can use the second method to `cd` into a directory, run a command, and then continue execution.

```
julia> cd(readdir, "temp_dir/")
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "code.jl" 
 "file.txt"

julia> cd("temp_dir/") do
           mkdir("subdir")
       end

julia> cd(readdir, "temp_dir/")
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "code.jl" 
 "file.txt"
 "subdir"
```

We can pass any function as the first argument, including custom ones (concisely written using a `do` block).

Comment: When I first tried `cd(run(\`some_cmd\`), "temp_dir/")` it didn't work. Now I see that you need a function reference to be called after CWD is changed.

Comment: @m33lky Ah, yep - you'd have to pass a function, whereas `run(\`some_cmd\`)` returns an actual value. You could use an anonymous function instead of a `do` block to achieve your result, as well! `cd(() -> run(\`some_cmd\`), "temp_dir/")`

Answer (score 1):

An option which is safe for use with concurrent tasks is `setenv(cmd, dir=some_working_dir)`. This will create a `Cmd` object which will get `some_working_directory` in the child process without interfering with the working directory in your Julia session.

For example,

```
julia> run(setenv(`ls`, dir="temp_dir"))
code.jl  file.txt
Process(setenv(`ls`; dir="temp_dir"), ProcessExited(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way which makes the shell user happy.

Just write

```
run(`bash -c """cd temp_dir && some_cmd"""`)
```

and we are good!

Bonus of this method is that these sub-shells are independent.  E.g., I want an external program to generate force field for me, as in a molecular dynamics simulation.  I need generate a tone of point-wise data.  I would write it in parallel (using `Threads`).  The `cd` function in Julia will somehow change the working directory for all threads while in the solution given above it is thread-safe.